# Difference between Native AOT and AOT in .NET Mobile Android/iOS

Tags: .net, xamarin.android, mono, .net-native, native-aot

.NET 7 brings Native AOT. How's it different than the AOT already available in .NET 6 Android app?

2nd question: Is the Xamarin Android/iOS .NET runtimes replaced by the .NET 6 Android/iOS runtimes?

Comment: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/04/15/net-7-preview-3.aspx Spend a few minutes there and things should be clear. For the second, the answer is yes.